# CorePlot polar plot

Tags: iphone, ios6, core-plot

It became apparent that I needed to attempt to modify CorePlot code to allow me to plot Polar/Radar plots, due to heavy memory usage trying to plot circles/spokes as ScatterPlots.

I realised I could continue to use CPTScatterPlot for the actual polar data, however somehow I needed to modify the drawGridLinesInContext, such that instead of straight lines at each location, CPTXCoordinate would draw the circular line, CPTYCoordinate would be ignored, and  CPTZCoordinate would draw the spokes.

I had to create new classes based on their XY siblings viz CPTPolarGraph, CPTPolarPlotSpace, CPTPolarAxisSet, CPTPolarAxis. The new code continues to use X and Y axis to plot those axes, however a Z axis was introduced to manage the spokes.

Now I seem to have cracked this, however if I scroll up and down, the circles continue to pass through the X and Y axis ticks, as they should do, but when I scroll left and right, the circles get redrawn and no longer sit on the ticks.

I obviously got some more debugging to do here, but was hoping for some pointers from the CorePlot crew, as to what might be happening
.
I can zip my modified version of CorePlot_1.1, including a example polar scatter plot, and forward if needs be.

Comment: We can't help without the code and maybe some screenshots of the problem.

Comment: Obviously you read the last paragraph of question, so where can I leave this modified version for you to check out. I don't have enough credit to leave screenshots.

Comment: You can put screenshots on any online sharing site and link them here. Same with the code, or you could put your modified version on Github.

Comment: checkout: http://www.whichtoolface.com/iOS/coreplot%20polar%20plots.html

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a pixel alignment issue. The tick drawing code aligns the tick marks with the pixel grid but the new axis drawing does not. Look at `CPTAlignRectToUserSpace()` and the other alignment functions in **CPTUtilities.h**.

Edit:
You also may need a custom setter method for the `zRange` in the plot space. Make it similar to the `xRange` and `yRange` setters. The notifications fired by these methods are important—they force other parts of the graph to redraw when the plot space changes.

Comment: I've been working recently on this Polar Plot, how would I contribute to the project?, I'm completely ignorant of working with github, other than downloading zip files.

Comment: Submit a [pull request](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/pulls). Open an issue asking for help if the GitHub instructions aren't clear.

Comment: Cheers for that, just have to work out how to fill area under and above curve, then should be ready to submit.

Comment: Oh, what would be the easiest way to alter a column of a CPTNumericData array, multiplying by M_PI/180.0. Default for Polar Plot would be to enter angles in radians, so need to convert degrees to radians within -(nullable id)numbersFromDataSourceForField:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange. Completed the other input methods.

Comment: This is not the place for this discussion. Open an issue on GitHub and we can discuss the code there.

Answer (score 0):

The positioning of the centreViewPoint tracks precisely, as the spokes  are always generated from the same point, wherever the centre is in the plotArea. The rings are also always generated from the same centre. 
It seems to me that somehow, the diameters of the rings when I scroll left right get changed from the first plot presentation, yet when I scrolled Up-down they don't. Notice that when the plot is scrolled to left edge or right edge the major rings are line up on the major ticks again, as are the minor.
I tried reversing the code such that only the CPTCoordinateY get plotted, and I see the same effect, except scrolling up-down exhibits the changing in ring diameter size. 
Now perhaps `CGPoint startViewPoint = [thePlotSpace plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:startPlotPoint];` which establishes the diameter of a ring from its x-coordinate, is not returning correctly. Although perhaps also the `locations` set are changing, but why should they if no zooming has been done. 
I'm kind of struggling here, as when I walk through the code the `locations` don't appear to change.

Comment: At whichtoolface.com/iOS/coreplot%20polar%20plots.html I've added a mp4 file to show what I'm talking about